# Use ReallocMem in dll for pointer first allocated in host app (Delphi XE)

Tags: delphi, pointers, memory

I have a record which i want to pass to dll, where it can be extended with more fields.
Here is what i have in main app:

```
type     
 THostInterface = record
    name:   string;
    x1:     single;
  end;
 PHostInterface =   ^THostInterface;
var
  pHI: PHostInterface; 

begin
  GetMem(pHI, SizeOf(THostInterface));
  dll_func(pHI);
  dll_func2(pHI);
end;
```

Here is what i want to have in dll: extend given record with some fields, main app doesnt care about its contents, but should be able to pass pointer to new extended record to another dll functions.

```
type
THostInterfaceNew = record
    name:   string;
    x1:     single;
    x2,x3:  single;
  end;
end;

procedure dll_func (var pHI:  PHostInterface);
begin
   ReallocMem(pHI,sizeOf(THostInterfaceNew)); // Access Violation!
   pHI^.x2:=1; 
end;

procedure dll_func2 (var pHI:  PHostInterfaceNew);
begin
   Writeln(pHI^.x2); // here i want to have value "1" 
end;
```

Using ReallocMem in dll leads to Access Violation, could u plz explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory manager that allocates memory must be the same memory manager that reallocates/frees it.  By default, an app and a DLL would be compiled with separate memory managers. You cannot allocate memory in the app using one memory manager and then reallocate/free it in the DLL using a different memory manager.

To make this work, the app and DLL must share a single memory manager, at least for data that passes over the DLL boundary.

If you compile both app and DLL with runtime packages enabled, they can share a single instance of the RTL, and thus a single instance of Delphi's native memory manager.  If runtime packages are not enabled, you can still share a single instance of Delphi's native memory manager by using the `ShareMem` or `SimpleShareMem` unit in both projects. See [Sharing Memory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Sharing_Memory) on Embarcadero's DocWiki.

Note that these approaches only work in Delphi/C++Builder projects, and require the app and DLL to be compiled in the same *version* of Delphi/C++Builder.

If the app is not written in Delphi/C++Builder, then you will have to resort to using an OS-provided memory management API for any memory that passes over the DLL boundary, such as:

- `LocalAlloc()` / `LocalReAlloc()` / `LocalFree()`
- `CoTaskMemAlloc()` / `CoTaskMemRealloc()` / `CoTaskMemFree()`
- `IMalloc` interface
- etc

Either way, this is just a bad design all around, IMHO.  It is safe to pass memory across the DLL boundary for the purpose of *reading from it* or *filling it*, but do not allocate the memory in one module and then realloc/free it in another module - Period.  Whoever allocates the memory should be the only one to realloc/free it.  This gives the allocator the freedom to decide *how* it wants to (re)allocate it (on the stack? on the heap? in a memory pool?).

If you want the DLL to reallocate the memory, then the DLL should be the one to allocate and free it as well.  Otherwise, make the app allocate, reallocate, and free the memory, and the DLL can simply fill the reallocated memory with values as needed.

Now, with that said, even if you did manage to reallocate the memory *safely*, the code you have shown would still fail to compile, since `dll_func2()` expects a **var reference** (why?) to a `PHostInterfaceNew` but you are passing it a `PHostInterface` instead. That will cause a "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" error.  You cannot mismatch types like that. You would need to remove the `var` reference and use a type-cast, eg:

```
procedure dll_func2 (pHI:  PHostInterfaceNew);

...

var
  pHI: PHostInterface; 
begin
  ...
  dll_func2(PHostInterfaceNew(pHI));
end;
```

Comment: `using the ShareMM unit` - it is ShareMEM, not ShareMM, also for execution speed much better to use SimpleShareMem.  But yes, it all is Delphi-only solution

Comment: Well, I guess it should work for c++Builder as well, although I may be wrong.